# BLoC custom transformer and switchMap not working as expected

Tags: flutter, concurrency, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
    EventTransformer<InitialEvent> someTransformer<InitialState>() {
    
    
    return (events, mapper) {
      
      final nonPausedStream = events.where(
          (event) => event.userActivity.eventState != eventUtils.statePause);
      
      
      final pausedStream = events.where(
          (event) => event.userActivity.eventState == eventUtils.statePause);
      
      
      return nonPausedStream.takeWhile((element) => element.userActivity.eventState != eventUtils.statePause)
          .asyncExpand(mapper).switchMap((p0) => pausedStream.asyncExpand((event) => Stream.value(event)));

    };
  }
```

I've been trying to separate events based upon whether they're in paused or running state but the "switchMap" does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this in bloc_concurrency package?